# Deploying Spring Boot app to AWS beanstalk

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying since yesterday to deploy a spring boot in Tomcat on AWS Beanstalk and I always have this exception being raised :

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageFilter': Initialization of bean failed;
      .....

       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
        at org.coursera.symptomserver.auth.config.OAuth2SecurityConfiguration$1.customize(OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java:212)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
 ...
```

In my local dev environment, I don't have this error. In my local dev, I developped on Tomcat 7 with the '1.0.2.RELEASE' version.

I created a war with that I deploy on Tomcat 7 instance in AWS Beanstalk and the error below always comes out. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a Spring Boot application to a standalone servlet container, it uses a special "embedded" servlet container, `ErrorPageFilter`, to handle application errors by forwarding requests to the configured error pages. The code in `org.coursera.symptomserver.auth.config.OAuth2SecurityConfiguration$1` is incorrectly assuming that this class is a `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` which is resulting in a `ClassCastException`.

The first thing to do is to make this code more robust by adding an `instanceof` check so that it only attempts the cast when it knows that it'll succeed. Secondly, as you're actually deploying to a standalone Tomcat instance, you'll need to apply this customisation to Tomcat by changing its `server.xml` or `context.xml` rather than doing it programatically.

Comment: I have the exact exception - I'm not a spring boot guru, can you please give me guidance on how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello I have created a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240159/spring-boot-war-file-on-tomcat-errorpagefilter-cannot-be-cast-to-tomcatembedded